# Generating proper paths in namespaced Rails scaffolds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, rails-generators

When you use `rails generate scaffold admin/user --model-name=User` or `rails generate scaffold_controller --model-name=User` it generates almost everything in a namespaced fashion.  You get `app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb` with your controller and `app/views/admin/users/` filled with your views.

The one thing it doesn't get right is your paths.  You have to manually go and replace references to `user_path` with `admin_user_path` and the like.  This is pretty tedious.

Is there a way to tell Rails to generate the paths to point to your new namespace, rather than the namespace that the model is in?

Using Rails 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With rails build-in generators you can't.

See the [generator source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/index.html.erb#L21) to understand why:

```
<td><%%= link_to 'Show', <%= singular_table_name %> %></td>
<td><%%= link_to 'Edit', edit_<%= singular_table_name %>_path(<%= singular_table_name %>) %></td>
<td><%%= link_to 'Destroy', <%= singular_table_name %>, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see, it goes with `edit_<%= singular_table_name %>_path` to generate the edit path, without considering name-spacing. (And haml-rails [does the same](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/haml/scaffold/templates/index.html.haml#L19))

---

The best thing to do, if you have time and patience for it, would be to fix this on the codebase and propose a PR. That's the main point of open-source after all.

If you go this direction, have a look first at open issues, I haven't dive deep into but it seems that different conversations are going on about that matter. Like https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13927 or https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21652

---

Or you can use existing gems like [Beautiful-Scaffold](https://github.com/rivsc/Beautiful-Scaffold) that seem to be supporting namepacing